# Intro to Metamathematics Kleene $\S54$ Lemma IId

Tags: recursive-algorithms, meta-math, formal-systems

In this section, Kleene builds a formal system for primitive recursive functions.  The beginning of the proof for lemma IId is skipped because it comes for general properties, but I must be missing something.

> We easily see, by general properties of $\vdash$, that $E^{\psi_{1}...\psi_{l}}_{f_{1}...f_{l}},E_{l+1}...E_k\vdash f_i($***x***$_1,...,$***x***$_{n_{i}}) = $ ***x***, if
>
> $f_i($***x***$_1,...,$***x***$_{n_{i}}) = $ ***x*** $\in E^{\phi_i}_{f_{i}}$

What is the justification in this?

(Sorry, I couldn't put more background information this is lemma four of five lemmas. It would be too much to describe in one question, so just refer to the text. Thanks)